# postgresql: Splitting multiple columns into rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hope you all are well.

Here is screenshot of my dataset[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZoXZ.png)

Now the real data set currently has almost three thousand rows, and what I'm striving to do is break down the contacts from twelve columns, to three.

```
Company name | Contact | Position | Email
FooFoo Inc   |    Me   |   ceo    | stuff@ 
FooFoo Inc   |   You   |   ceo    | stuff@   
FooFoo Inc   |  Friend |   ceo    | stuff@
FooFoo Inc   |  Picard |   cto    | stuff@
Pear Co..... etc.
```

Any recommendations on how to approach this? 
Thanks all!

Comment: `SELECT` individual data groups and `UNION` them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
select company_name, primary_contact contact, contact_position position, email
union all select company_name, contact_2, contact_2_position, contact_2_email
union all select company_name, contact_3, contact_3_position, contact_3_email
union all select company_name, contact_4, contact_4_position, contact_4_email
```

Comment: You're a saint :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a lateral join:

```
select t.company_name, v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.contact, t.contact_position, t.email),
             (t.contact_2, t.contact_2_position, t.contact_2_email),
             (t.contact_3, t.contact_3_position, t.contact_3_email),
             . . .
     ) v(contact, contact_position, email);
```

You probably want to add:

```
where v.contact is not null
```

but that is not obvious from your sample data.